# Extract attachement from Outlook Contacts

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm wondering if anyone managed to build a code to extract attachements within Outlook contacts? I have a lot of contacts in my outlook 2010 with several attachements and would like to create a copy for backup. Also, if an automated way exist, is it possible to link the downloaded attachement to the contacts?

update
I have used several pieces of code to do what i want but getting a "User-defined type not defined". Anyone know hoe to avoid that error?

```
    Option Explicit
Sub GetAttachments()
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim contactFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem As Outlook.Item
    Dim ContactItem As Object
    Dim Attmt As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set contactFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    Set myItem = contactFolder.Items
    Set Attmt = myItem.Attachments
    i = 0
' Check each contacts for attachments
    For Each ContactItem In contactFolder.Items
' Save any attachments found
        For Each Attmt In ContactItem.Attachments
        ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
            FileName = "C:\Temp\" & Attmt.FileName
            Attmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            i = i + 1
         Next Attmt
    Next ContactItem
End Sub
```

Comment: something like this? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343834/runtime-error-91-outlook-save-attchments)

Answer (score 0):

Use ContactItem.Attachments collection. To save an attachment, call Attachment.SaveAsFile.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro or add-in to get the job done. Be aware, VBA macros are not designed for distributing the solution on multiple PCs. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information about VBA macros in Outlook.

If you need to automate Outlook from another applications, see [How to automate Outlook by using Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220595).

As Dmitry suggested, you can use the [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Attachment class to save the attached file on the disk.

```
Sub SaveAttachment() 
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.ContactItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then 
   If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "ContactItem" Then 
     Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem 
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
     'Prompt the user for confirmation 
     Dim strPrompt As String 
     strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
     If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
       myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _ 
       myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName 
     End If 
   Else 
     MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type." 
   End If
 End If
End Sub
```

To attach a file anew you can use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx) method of the Attachments class which creates a new attachment in the Attachments collection.

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", _ 
 olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I'm going to try to build something(really not an expert in VBA) and see how it goes

Comment: I have tried to modify some codes to get what i want but i get an "User-defined type not defined". Do you see anything obvious?......it doesn't seems i can past my code in comments......

Comment: you get this error message when a subroutine contains code that uses the Microsoft DAO Object Library, and the library is not referenced. check your References on the Tools menu > References and look for `Microsoft DAO Object Library`

Comment: The Microsoft DAO library was indeed missing but it didn't correct that error. After looking at the code again, i realised i was missing an "s" in Outlook.items. Now i get error 438 that keeps pointing to my set Attmt argument

Comment: You didn't declare the `Attmt` object correctly. According to the code it should be declared as Outlook.Attachment (without 's at the end).